# RestSharp error when shared as a dependency and different publicKeyTokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docusignapi, restsharp

Using APIs from `Docusign`, `Twilio` and `Auth0`. All 3 have `RestSharp.dll` as a dependency.

If I use the `RestSharp.dll` included with the `Docusign` package, `Docusign` works well but `Auth0` and `Twillio` give errors:

> Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=104.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

If I use the normal `RestSharp.dll` (Install-Package RestSharp), `Twilio` and `Auth0` work fine but I get an error when using Docusign:

> Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=100.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5xxxxxxxxxxxx'

Adding binding redirects does not solve the issue. Without binding redirects, I get this error in the log:

> Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: MAJOR VERSION.

If I do use a binding redirect:

> Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY
>   TOKEN.

Binding redirect code:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-105.2.3.0" newVersion="105.2.3.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Temporarily solved the issue by renaming the RestSharp.dll that was included with the Docusign package to "RestSharpDocusign.dll" and copied that into my project.

I modified the assembly bindings so that when version 100.0.0.0 was called it would load the special "RestSharpDocusign.dll" with the publicKeyToken Docusign wanted. Anything else would utilize the standard RestSharp.dll with a null publicKeyToken.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="null" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="100.0.0.1-105.2.3.0" newVersion="105.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="598062e77f915f75" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="100.0.0.0" href="ult/RestSharpDocusign.dll" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Seems kinda nutty that at this stage of the game we're reduced to playing these games straight outta 90's DLL Hell.

Comment: You're telling me! Luckily the DocuSign API is open so I was able to update RestSharp and recompile the DLL. Once I added that into my project everything worked OK.

Comment: For me it was the HelloSign API triggering this.

Comment: Is it still a temporarily solution?

Comment: 7 years later this saved my bacon with a RestSharp 105.2.3.0 vs 109.0.1.0 problem. ChatGPT claimed that just using 'null' in publicKeyToken field of the binding redirect would resolve the signed/unsigned issue but it was wrong, this solution was necessary.