# RestSharp Assembly Binding

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to map RestSharp 105.2.3.0 to RestSharp 106.5.4.0 using assembly binding, but it fails.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="null" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-106.5.4.0" newVersion="106.5.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I am using the version from nuGet:

```
  <package id="RestSharp" version="106.5.4" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Log entries:

> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:ConsoleClient/bin/Debug/RestSharp.DLL.
>
> WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN
> ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834840/8695782 this sounds like it's related.

Comment: I tried this code and it fails:  <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="null" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="100.0.0.1-106.5.4.0" newVersion="106.5.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="598062e77f915f75" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-106.5.4.0" newVersion="106.5.4.0" />
        <codeBase version="106.5.4.0" href="ult/RestSharpDocusign.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: There is no real advantage to use RestSharp anymore. Id seriously consider using the more modern HttpClient via the IHttpClientFactory interface

Comment: I am using a nuGet packages that references it. I could try to just add the project and change the reference, but I prefer the nuGet https://github.com/hubspot-net/HubSpot.NET

Comment: I found out that those versions of RestSharp have breaking changes. I downloaded the HubSpot.NET project and changed the reference. I stopped using the nuGet package. Assembly binding fails, when there are breaking changes. It is a best practice to just change assembly versions.